# When I create a variable of an abstract data type and store an existing object in it, how much more memory does it use?

Tags: java, object, data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation, user-defined-types

Suppose there's an abstract datatype defined by a class A.
We create an object of it and store it in a variable of the datatype A:

```
A obj = new A ( );
```

Now we declare a new variable obj2 (of the same datatype A). And then initialize it using the variable obj, i.e. :

```
A obj2; 
obj2 = obj;
```

Now I know that obj2 and obj point to the same memory location. Because if I change the value of any attribute of obj, the same change occurs automatically in obj2 and vice versa.
So clearly the memory being consumed by obj and obj2 is not the double of what was being consumed only by obj. But then how much more memory is being consumed???

Edited:

```
class A {

    int num;
}

class B {

    A obj;

    void main() {
        Stack<A> stack = new Stack<A>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            stack.push(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, when I create the stack and store stuff in it, will the memory consumed still be equal to total memory of all references that I create or will the stack consume some memory as well?

Comment: you cannot create an object of an abstract datatype

Comment: https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue029.html Determining memory usage in Java

Answer (score 1):

What you created is another reference to the original object.

This is basically a "pointer" to the place where your object is located in the heap.

For a 64 bit JVM, the size of a reference is 64 bits, unless you have configured the JVM to use compressed pointers.

For the edited part:
Stack is another object with its own fields, and therefore when you create new Stack, it consumes memory in heap. *BUT* when you call push(..), stack actually *doesn't* consume more memory, because it stores refrences to objects which are "inside" the stack in array: `Object[] elementData`. By default this array has size of 10, which means you can push up to 10 elements to the stack without increasing its size.

I recommend reading source code of the Stack class to understand how it works and what fields it has.

More info about how much space java objects occupy:
https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml